# Как вывести блок за пределы родительского (с overflow)

Tags: css, html

Привет!
Есть вопрос.
Например имеем родительского блок.
В нем есть дочерний.
Как вывести этот блок за пределы первого, если первый с overflow?

Заготовку набросал - https://jsfiddle.net/yaph9oq4/

```css
#blok1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}
#blok2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -120px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blok1">
    <div id="blok2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
.parent-main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#blok1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#blok2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-main">
  <div id="blok1">
    <div id="blok2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```